# Oozie java action fails with Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, oozie

I am facing the below issue when I try to run oozie java action. This issue is not occurring in all clusters. On some specific clusters I see this issue.

Sharelib of oozie have lower version of jackson-databind

```
sharelib version: jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar
version available in oozie workflow lib: jackson-databind-2.10.4.jar
```

Please let me know a way to figure out which jar is given precedence by oozie. If sharelib is given precedence how to change to give priority to workflow lib.

```
 <workflow-app name="AppConfiguration Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
        <credentials>
            <credential name="hcat" type="hcat">
                <property>
                    <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
                    <value>${hiveThriftUrl}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
                    <value>${hiveServicePrincipal}</value>
                </property>
            </credential>
        </credentials>
        <start to="AppConfiguration"/>
        <kill name="Kill">
            <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
        </kill>
        <action name="AppConfiguration" cred="hcat">
            <java>
                <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                <configuration>
                    <property>
                        <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.java</name>
                        <value>hive</value>
                    </property>
                </configuration>
                <main-class>com.conf.appConfiguration</main-class>
                <arg>${nameNode}</arg>
                <arg>${nameNode}${jobDir}/conf.yaml</arg>
            </java>
            <ok to="End"/>
            <error to="Kill"/>
        </action>   
        <end name="End"/>
    </workflow-app>



<workflow-app name="AppConfiguration Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <credentials>
        <credential name="hcat" type="hcat">
            <property>
                <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
                <value>${hiveThriftUrl}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
                <value>${hiveServicePrincipal}</value>
            </property>
        </credential>
    </credentials>
    <start to="AppConfiguration"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="AppConfiguration" cred="hcat">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.java</name>
                    <value>hive</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <main-class>com.conf.appConfiguration</main-class>
            <arg>${nameNode}</arg>
            <arg>${nameNode}${jobDir}/conf.yaml</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>   
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

exception stack trace

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.runActionMain(LauncherAM.java:410)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.access$300(LauncherAM.java:55)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$2.run(LauncherAM.java:223)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.run(LauncherAM.java:217)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$1.run(LauncherAM.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:141)
Caused by: org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain$JavaMainException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/InputCoercionException
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:58)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:35)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/InputCoercionException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers.<clinit>(JdkDeserializers.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findDefaultDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1861)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.findStdDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:167)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:131)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:479)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4405)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3182)
    at com.conf.appConfiguration.readConfiguration(AnalyticsPurger.java:252)
    at com.conf.appConfiguration.purge(AnalyticsPurger.java:82)
    at com.conf.appConfiguration.main(AnalyticsPurger.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:55)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 40 more
Failing Oozie Launcher, com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/InputCoercionException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/InputCoercionException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers.<clinit>(JdkDeserializers.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findDefaultDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1861)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.findStdDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:167)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:131)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:479)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4405)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3182)
    at com.alu.motive.ae.purge.AnalyticsPurger.readConfiguration(AnalyticsPurger.java:252)
    at com.alu.motive.ae.purge.AnalyticsPurger.purge(AnalyticsPurger.java:82)
    at com.alu.motive.ae.purge.AnalyticsPurger.main(AnalyticsPurger.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:55)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.runActionMain(LauncherAM.java:410)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.access$300(LauncherAM.java:55)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$2.run(LauncherAM.java:223)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.run(LauncherAM.java:217)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$1.run(LauncherAM.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:141)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `oozie.use.system.libpath=false` in job properties?

Comment: I need hive sharelib. I am enabling it by                 <property>
                    <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.java</name>
                    <value>hive</value>  
                </property>. Without hive sharelib I get exceptions like org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/InvalidTableException

Comment: @Madhu, I think there is no way of telling Oozie to prioritize the "lib" in your workspace. Do you absolutely need to use version 2.10.4 of the conflicting jar?

Comment: It would be better to build your app against the same jar versions that are used in the sharelib. Seems there is no other way around. Or upgrade sharelib itself

Comment: yes, I need 2.10.4 jar. As a workaround I built a shaded jar. with shaded jar problem seems to be resolved